# Interpreting an input of raw binary data and pulling certain values (Python)

Tags: python, binary

I am creating a Python program with which I need some assistance. The program I'm creating works as such.

> The user inputs a raw binary input of 0's and 1's from a file. I then must be able to read this data in a particular manner. I want to read each line separately (180 binary digits long with multiple lines) and skip each line's first 30 binary numbers and the last 30 binary numbers. I will then store the collected data (of each line), missing the first and last 30 digits. This will be output to the user in a .txt file. I know how to read from a file and write a file, but I do not understand how to save or write the data I'm only interested in.

This is what I have so far so the user can input their file:

```
filename = input("What is the name of your file:")
fi = open(filename, "r")
```

This isn't much, but again, I lack the knowledge to interpret the data.

Here's an shortened example (ignoring the first and last 3 digits):

Let's say the file *binary.txt* contains the following:

```
000111000111000111
111000111000111000
```

Ran through my program, the output or newly saved file would contain:

```
111000111000
000111000111
```

I haven't found a way to interpret the binary data as I need to, so I have not tried any solutions. Turning each line of binary into a list may help determine the position of the data I want extracted. Would that be the right way to do it, and can that be achieved?

Comment: Post some sample data. The file contains *0* and *1* characters (meaning each binary digit is actually a *char*)? In your example you have 2 18 digit strings separated by space. Where does that fall with respect to 180 chars and 30 drops at the endpoints? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I will be working with .bit files but want to understand the context with a .txt file first. The example was just a shortened example of the desired result I'd like.

Comment: i added some another answer o another question so I had to wait.. below is your solution fro mwhat I get. but also as mentioned by crisfati you need to clarify a bit ore about what exactly do you want and keep your questions concise...